# Using IF/ELSE IF/ELSE statements in Attribute Expressions for String Fields

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I am trying to do build some Attribute Expressions using Arcade and I am having some issues with it returns the `else` statement. I know that there are features that would return true because I have used these parameters under filters before.

```
var parksign = $feature.ParkSign2;
var signpole = $feature.SignPole1;

if(parksign == 'One on bus stop pole, 2nd on breakaway in ground, grass, dirt'){
    return 'Yes'
}else if(signpole == 'Yes, Metro breakaway in ground, grass, or dirt'){
    return 'Yes'
}else{
    return 'No'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After halfway completing this post yesterday I ended up finding the answer. The fields that I was attempting to use logical statements on were configured with `Domains` or a `List of Values`. When you configure using these fields everywhere else in the platform the domain alias is displayed in the filter or function, but when you configure using `Arcade` or `Attribute Expressions` `$feature.SignPole1` is looking for the Domain Code. If you want to look at the Name/Label you have to use `DomainName($feature.SignPole1)`.

For assistance you can reference you can look at the `feature class information > data > fields > list of values`. [image: feature class fields info]

OR

Under the Attribute Expressions panel `globals > $feature > find you data column`[image: Attribute Expression field list functions]